# Using caringcaribou to do fuzz, an unknown interface type “None” appears

Tags: can-bus, fuzzing

I want to use caringcaribou to fuzz the vehicle can bus. I connected the pcan and then used two commands "sudo modprobe can", "sudo ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000", then I used "ip link show can0", can see the information of can0, but I use the command  "cc.py fuzzer random", an error of unknown interface type "None" appeared. I used cc.py -i can0 fuzzer random and still got the same error. I couldn't get any message by using the command "candump can0" , but my colleague can capture the messages of the can bus normally by using pcan view.How to solve this problem, thank you very much[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in interface setup. you need to make UP your interface:

```html
sudo ip link set up can0
```

And in CaringCaribou, you need to make a file called canrc in root and give the following content:

```html
[default]
interface = socketcan
channel = can0
```

I hope I helped you today !!